# Thread stops itself

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been searching for a solution for a long time, but I wasn't able to find one, so I'll ask my question here.
I have a thread which is started when the program starts and supposed to be idle until it is enabled by the application. Simple code example:

```
private class UpdaterThread extends Thread {

    private static final int UPDATE_RATE = 50;
    private Timer updateTimer = new Timer();

    private boolean enabled;

    public void run() {

        while (!closeRequested) {

            // If this is uncommented, the thread works as it's supposed to.
            // System.out.print("");

            if (enabled) {

                Snapshot next = getNextSnapshot(1f / UPDATE_RATE);
                System.out.println("Got next Snapshot");
                updateTimer.sync(UPDATE_RATE);
                System.out.println("Push");
                currentSnapshot = next;
            }
        }
    }

    public void enable() {

        enabled = true;
    }

    public void disable() {

        enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read a variable, which the JIT believes you didn't modify, it inlines the value.  If you then modify the value later, it is too late, the value has been embedded in the code.

A simple way to avoid this is to use `volatile` but you would still have the problem than the thread is busy waiting for the value to change and there doesn't appear to be a good reason to do this.  Another option is to add code which confuses the JIT do it doesn't do this optimisation.  An empty synchronized block is enough but a friendlier way is to use Thread.sleep() which at least doesn't use up all your CPU.

I suggest using a `volatile` fields and sleeping with a period of 10-100 ms.  However a simpler option is to not start the thread until it is needed.

Comment: A multithreaded solution with the avoidable polling still in, but with the gross CPU waste replaced by a latency boosting sleep() loop.  SWOmetimes, I wonder why OS/languages bother with all those sycnro primitives and wrappers.  You have 183k rep and you suggest a sleep() loop?

Comment: @MartinJames A sleep loop is the simplest change.  I suggest not running the thread at all until you want it to run.

Answer (score 0):

since run() is called when the thread is started, you could just wait until later in the program to start it, also threads do not extend "Thread" but implements "Runnable" so the class definition would look like:

```
public class UpdaterThread implements Runnable
```

hope it helps :D